# Angular scope dynamic?

Tags: angularjs

I can create a scope of dynamic way?

Therefore I have taxonomies and terms that are created via admin, so I serious within a scope , I need the names of these taxonomies in scope , but the way I'm doing is not working very well .

Any help is welcome

LAYOUT

```
<md-checkbox ng-checked="exists(term.slug, tax.slug)" ng-click="toggle(term.slug, tax.slug)"></md-checkbox>
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.toggle = function (term, tax) {
    if(!$scope.item.tax) { $scope.item.tax = []; }
    var idx = $scope.item.tax[tax].indexOf(term);
    if (idx > -1) $scope.item.tax[tax].splice(idx, 1);
    else $scope.item.tax[tax].push(term);
};

$scope.exists = function (term, tax) {
    if(!$scope.item.tax) $scope.item.tax = [];
    if($scope.item.tax[tax]) return $scope.item.tax[tax].indexOf(term) > -1;
};
```

JSBIN :
https://jsbin.com/decafebuda/edit?html,js,console,output

The closer I got , new JSBin:
https://jsbin.com/nejimunizo/1/edit?html,js,console,output

FINISH!

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="tax[t.slug][term.slug]"></md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Define "is not working very well". Tell us what you expect this code to do, and what it does instead. Precisely. You should also tell where this md-checkbox directive come from. It's not a standard one.

Comment: md-checkbox from Angular Material, error is: Error: $scope.item.tax[tax] is undefined

Comment: And what is unclear in this message? You define $scope.item.tax as an empty array, and right after, you're trying to access the element at the tax index (which doesn't exist, since t's an empty array) and to call indexOf() on this undefined element.

Comment: The scope to which the error refers to is $ scope.item.tax[tax] and not the $scope.item.tax .
But thank you, you've helped a lot :)

Comment: Precisely: $scope.item.tax is defined. The message doesn't complain about that. The value of $scope.item.tax is an empty array: `[]`. So, $scope.item.tax[tax], which is what the error complains about, is indeed undefined: there is nothing at the tax index of the array, since the array is empty. And calling indexOf on this undefined variable thus causes an exception.

Comment: I create JSbin for explained better my problem: https://jsbin.com/decafebuda/edit?html,js,console,output